# xcodebuild fails when specifying arch or sdk when a target builds for multiple archs

Tags: iphone, xcode, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

I have a target that builds an iPhone app.  In the course of building the app, it builds an i386 (OS X) commandline target, set up as dependencies.  This works just fine through XCode, but when I attempt to specify -arch or -sdk from the commandline, the build fails with an error:

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform
```

This is not surprising.  xcodebuild is propagating the -sdk and -arch commands to the dependant projects, making them to build the command line tool for iOS which promptly fails.  What I want is to build the dependant projects for OS X.

To be clear, here is the build order:

- iPhone app starts building

  Xcode detects unmet dependency, a .plist file

  Xcode runs code to meet the dependency which involves building an OSX binary through a subproject

  Xcode runs the built OS X binary which generates the plist file

  Xcode continues building the iPhone app

How do I specify the SDK for the primary target but not the dependencies?